# Rails 3 Mobiscroll Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobiscroll

I am running a Rails application on Heroku and tried to import the [mobiscroll-rails](https://github.com/Dinuz/mobiscroll-rails) gem. The gem works fine on heroku, however, whenever I try to run any rails/rake command on my local machine, I get the following error:

couldn't find file 'mobiscroll.list'
  (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mobiscroll-rails-2.3.1/vendor/assets/javascripts/mobiscroll.js:11)

I am running Windows 7, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.9.

Anyone have any hints on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/Dinuz/mobiscroll-rails/commit/972c89db2dcfa85fef144ddb9bd0e036d0209414

Looks like you're using an old version of the gem. To fix this, just follow what that commit does - rename 'vendor/assets/javascripts/mobilscroll.list.js' to 'vendor/assets/javascripts/mobiscroll.list.js'